# Get json data in ajax every 5 seconds

Tags: ajax, json

I have a script that makes a json request every 5 seconds, but I can not display the alert in the success method.

The javavascript is:

```
<script>
 function repite() {
     $.ajax({
          url: 'http://www.comparador.local/ProxmoxAPI/test.php',
          dataType: 'json',
          cache: false,
          success: function(data) {

            alert(data.test);
            },
            error: function(){
            }
         });

     setTimeout(repite,5000);
 }

 repite();
</script>
```

The result of petition:

```
{"test":0}
```

Headers of petition:

```
Accept  application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding gzip, deflate
Accept-Language es-ES,es;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3
Cache-Control   no-cache
Connection  keep-alive
Host    www.comparador.local
Origin  null
Pragma  no-cache
User-Agent  Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; rv:26.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/26.0
```

Comment: What's any browsers error console saying?

Comment: HI @GhostGambler, I edited my script, change method "success" by "complete" and alert(data.toSource());

Comment: I meant if the console throws an error, see this for a detailed explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Debugging_JavaScript

Comment: Hi @GhostGambler sorry but is my first question in this page, I edited the post with the headers of petition.

Comment: Maybe add an alert box in the error handler to see if that's firing?